# Classificação por scoring

Tags: algoritmo

Eu tenho um quiz, são 10 perguntas, cada uma com até 4 respostas. Precisava dar um peso para cada resposta para no final ter um score que classifique ele em 4 perfis.

Limitação técnica: eu só consigo somar, dividir, multiplicar de um score global.

Dúvida: Somado o score preciso classificar em um de 4 perfis. Alguém sabe alguma tecnica de classificação que permita isso dado as limitações que tenho?

Comment: Por favor, quem der negativo diga o motivo. Obrigado!

Comment: Quero ver se entendi o problema... Seu score é devido as suas limitações? Se pudesse apenas contar as respostas em quantas foram do tipo A, B, C ou D teria o mesmo efeito?

Comment: Exatamente! O problema é que a ferramenta não deixa. Por isso queria saber se existe alguma brincadeira matemática que conseguiria classificar

Answer (score 1):

Pensa assim:
Alternativa A: 1 ponto
Alternativa B: 20 pontos
Alternativa C: 300 pontos
Alternativa D: 4000 pontos

Se uma pessoa responder a mesma alternativa até 10 vezes, o score nunca se repetirá ao valor de qualquer uma das outras alternativas. Exemplo: Se o score for 4982, a pessoa respondeu 2 A, 4 B, 3 C e 1 D. Um algoritmo pra isso seria dividir pelo maior valor de peso e pegar o resto para ir fazendo mais 3 divisões, sendo que cada valor da divisão vai dar a quantidade de cada alternativa. Não sei se pode pegar o resto, se não puder, teria que subtrair o maior valor de peso do score, contando quantas subtrações vão ser possíveis antes que o resultado seja negativo ou zero. Aí pegaria o segundo score mais alto e assim sucessivamente, até que chegar no menor valor de score e a subtração terminar em zero.